# Mapping multiple parameters of a function to specific values

Tags: plotting, evaluation, syntax

I am a little bit confused by the documentation for `Apply` (`@@`).

I want to define a list of parameters, for instance:

```
parameters = {{1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1/3}, {2, 1/4}, {0.5, 1/5}};
```

Then I have a function:

```
(b/a)*((a/x)^(b+1))
```

Now I want to map the pair (a,b) to the values defined in `parameters` and generate a plot for each pair of parameters in the same graph.

Now the plot syntax would look something like this:

```
p = Plot[Evaluate[myfunction /@ parameters], {x, 0, 3},
         AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, f}, PlotStyle -> styles]
```

What I struggle with, is getting the syntax right in the following part:

```
myfunction /@ parameters
```

How do I need to define this so I get a proper map of (a,b) to my list of parameters? To be honest, I am not very satisfied with the documentation for `Map`. Are there better tutorials?

Comment: Though old and extremely limited in scope , there's always the [Flash tutorials](http://documents.wolfram.com/flash/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two main ways of accomplishing this, both have their merits, but `Map` may be easier to understand initially.  For instance, using `(b/a)*((a/x)^(b+1))` I would do the following,

```
(#[[2]]/#[[1]])(#[[1]]/x)^(#[[2]]+1)& /@ parameters
```

where `#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]` are `a` and `b`, respectively. But, this makes it difficult to read, alternatively you can use `With` to improve the readability, as follows,

```
With[{a = #[[1]], b = #[[2]]}, (b/a)*((a/x)^(b+1))]& /@ parameters
```

It is longer, but it is more readable. I tend to use `With` in this way. The second method is to use `Apply`, as outlined by [R.M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5218/52). Here `With` can also be used,

```
With[{a = #1, b = #2}, (b/a)*((a/x)^(b+1))]& @@@ parameters
```

but it is less likely to be confusing when you come back to the code a month later.

Comment: Ok! Does the "#" in front designate it as a parameter? Does the number designate the order, so that the program knows which value from {number1, number2} to map? Why do we have 3 @'s. How does this "level" theory work?

Comment: @Chris The `#` is a formal parameter known as a  [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html). `#` is shorthand for `#1`. In my example using `Map`, `#[[1]]` refers to the first element of the first parameter. As noted by RM, `Apply` differs in that it replaces the `Head` of an expression, so `Apply[f, {x,y}]` (shorthand `f@@{x,y}`) becomes `f[x,y]`. The `@@@` is shorthand for `Apply[f, {{1,2},{3,4}}, {1}]` which results in `{f[1,2], f[3,4]}`. Because the elements become arguments, `#1` becomes `a` and `#2` becomes `b` in your question.

Comment: For the last approach (using `@@@`) you could use `Function[{a, b}, (b/a)*((a/x)^(b + 1))]` instead of `With`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another way:

```
parameters = {{1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1/3}, {2, 1/4}, {0.5, 1/5}};

myfunction[{a_, b_}] := (b/a)*((a/x)^(b + 1))

Plot[myfunction /@ parameters, {x, 0, 3}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Using plain `x` here is not local; you should consider using `\[FormalX]` instead.  The example above is "safe" because `x` is localized by `Plot` (it would not be if you used `Plot[ Evaluated @ ... ]` instead of `Evaluated -> True`).  On the other hand if you accidentally assign a value to x and then try something like `myfunction[{1, 1/3}] /. x -> 5` it will not behave as expected.  [Formal Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) are symbols that *Mathematica* will not let you assign a value to, protect you from yourself in a case like this.  It is a good idea to use them if you are going to create a definition with a "floating" undefined symbol like `x` in the example above.

Comment: Can you expand upon `\[FormalX]` and why it is useful? Why does it work here, when `x` would not?

Comment: @rcollyer well here it is not *needed* because `Evaluated -> True` rather than `Evaluated @` localizes `x` anyway, but generally speaking it's a bad idea to float around a global variable that's not supposed to have a value, because at some point it might be assigned one accidentally.  That's what the [Formal Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) are for. (I know you know this.)

Comment: I did know that, I just tend not to use them. I was trying to get you to expand your answer a little ... :P But, `Evaluated` is news to me; it does not show up in the docs, but is in `Options[Plot]`.

Comment: `Evaluated -> True` was new to me too

Comment: @rcollyer is that any good?

Comment: @R.M it's not my discovery but I simply cannot remember who posted it here first.

Comment: Indeed, it's not very widely used here. [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4801/5) seems to be the only place where it is used... Do you foresee any issues with setting it to `True` instead of `Automatic` as default?

Comment: @R.M well, it rather significantly changes the behavior of `Plot`, doesn't it?  I can trace it (on SE) back to at least [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7307532/618728) but I'm not sure that's the first time I saw it.

Comment: Well, it does change, but I can't think of an instance where I have not desired this behaviour...

Comment: Yes, it is, and +1.

Comment: Incidentally, the `Evaluated` trick is on [Szabolcs' web page](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php). It is about 1/3 the way down the page.

Comment: @rcollyer outside of SE I can track it back to at least [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/May/msg00866.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can define your function as an anonymous function and use `Apply` at level 1 or `@@@`:

```
myfunction[x_] := #2/#1 ((#1/x)^(#2 + 1)) &
Plot[Evaluate[myfunction[x] @@@ parameters], {x, 0, 3},  
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, f}]
```

[image]

---

Think of `Apply` as something that replaces the [Head](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html) of an expression. For example, the head of `g[a, b]` is `g`. Now if you apply `f` to that expression, you get:

```
f @@ g[a, b]
(* Out= f[a, b] *)
```

You see that the head has been replaced with `f`. The long form of `Apply` also takes a third argument, where you can specify the [Level](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Level.html) that you want it to act on i.e., you can write `Apply[f, expr, {level}]`.

`Apply` at level 1 is used very often, that it has its own shorthand, which is `@@@` and is what I've used above. Here's an example showing the difference between `@@` and `@@@`:

```
f @@ g[h[a, b], h[c, d]]
(* Out= f[h[a, b], h[c, d]] *)

f @@@ g[h[a, b], h[c, d]]
(* Out= g[f[a, b], f[c, d]] *)
```

Comment: I was working so hard to include both methods, but you stole my thunder, +1. :)

Comment: Is that & at the end of the line where myfunction is defined necessary? Why can't I defined the function, put a ; at the end and then run the plot?

Comment: @Chris he's being clever. As pointed out by Mr.Wizard, `x` is global, and within the bounds of `Evaluate` it would take on it's global value. What that construct does is localize `x` to the local form.

Comment: @Chris Yes, it is necessary. The `&` is what completes the pure function definition and it won't work without it. My definition above is a mix of named patterns (`x_`) which localizes the variable `x` and slots (`#`) which take the parameter values when you apply at level 1.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution, which uses replacement rules, and is syntactically closest to your original code (and, unlike most other solutions, doesn't require you to rewrite either `myfunction` or `parameters`).

```
p = Plot[Evaluate[myfunction /. {a->#1, b->#2}& @@@ parameters], {x, 0, 3},
                  AxesOrigin -> {0,0}, AxesLabel -> {x,f}, PlotStyle -> styles]
```

However, in case you can rewrite `myfunction`, the simplest solution would be to make it a function of the parameters:

```
myfunction[a_, b_] := (b/a)*((a/x)^(b+1))
p = Plot[Evaluate[myfunction @@@ parameters], {x, 0, 3},
                  AxesOrigin -> {0,0}, AxesLabel -> {x,f}, PlotStyle -> styles]
```

Or maybe cleaner (but slightly more verbose):

```
myfunction[a_, b_, x_] := (b/a)*((a/x)^(b+1))
p = Plot[Evaluate[myfunction[##,x]& @@@ parameters], {x, 0, 3},
                  AxesOrigin -> {0,0}, AxesLabel -> {x,f}, PlotStyle -> styles]
```

On the other hand, if you cannot change `myfunction`, but can change how your `parameters` are written, you could directly write the latter as rules:

```
parameters = {{a->1/2, b->1/2}, {a->1, b->1/3}, {a->2, b->1/4}, {a->0.5, b->1/5}};
```

Then your plot call would just read

```
p = Plot[Evaluate[myfunction /. parameters], {x, 0, 3},
                  AxesOrigin -> {0,0}, AxesLabel -> {x,f}, PlotStyle -> styles]
```