# Show the locus of the vertex of parabola

Tags: plotting, manipulate

For the parabola `y = a x^2+ b x + c` I want to see the **locus** of the vertex as `b` varies (with `a` and `c` to be parameters). What are the ways to plot the locus of the parabola dynamically in *Mathematica*?

I am very new to *Mathematica*, so I could figure out only basic `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[a x^2 + b x + c, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1], 
   {a, -20, 20}, {b, -20, 20}, {c, -10, 10}
 ]
```

I would like to see the locus parabola appearing in the same manner as in the [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32456/24604), if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more details about exactly what you want? As it is, this is likely to be closed as being unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want something like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32444/plotting-an-epicycloid). A animation where the locus of the vertex of the parabola is plotted as i manipulate a,b,c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 plot1 = Plot[a x^2 + b x + c, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 40, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Small];
 plot3 = If[a == 0, Graphics[], 
   ParametricPlot[{-u / (2 a), a (-u / (2 a))^2 + u (-u / (2 a)) + c}, {u, -b, b}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]];

 Show[plot1, plot3],

 {{a, -2}, -20, 20}, {b, -20, 20}, {c, -10, 10}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> True]
```

[image]

**Edit** Another method to visualize locus:

```
Manipulate[
  f[x_, i_] := a x^2 + (b + i) x + c;
  tmp = Table[f[x, i], {i, -20, 20, 5}];

  plot1 = Plot[tmp, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1];
  plot2 = Plot[Tooltip[-a x^2 + c, "Locus"], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}];

  Show[plot1, plot2],

{a, -20, 20}, {b, -20, 20}, {c, -10, 10}, TrackedSymbols :> True]
```

[image]

**Edit2** Note on connection between first and second parts. Notice in 'plot3' we have used parametric form.

```
Solve[{x == -b / (2 a), y == a x^2 + b x + c}, {x, y}] // FullSimplify
```

$y=c-\frac{b^2}{4 a}$ and $x^2=\frac{b^2}{4 a^2}$.

So, we may come back from parametric to cartesian equation
$y= - a x^2 + c$

(this equation is used in `plot2`).

Comment: Thank you. And how to find the equation of that locus?

Comment: @LokeshJaddu, in the second visualisation it is `-a x^2 + c`. In practice it is more complicated, but in `Manipulate` your `a` and `c` change sign from `-` to `+`, so we may use this very simple representation.

Comment: I understood that its -a x^2 + c . But isn't there a way to let mathematica figure that equation out for me?

Comment: You can use `GroebnerBasis[]` for eliminating parameters.