# How to visualize the Cremona method for cardioid generation

Tags: graphics, geometry, code-request, generative-art

I saw this on Twitter and found the [cardioid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cardioid.html) drawing quite satisfying. I don't know much mathematical background, and was wondering if I can draw this using *Mathematica*.

[image: equispaced points]

And this one apparently take $60$ points $\pmod {60}$.

[image: cardioid envelope]

With some extension:

[image: other envelopes]

**My best attempt only goes as far as this:**

```
Graphics[Circle[]]
```

I can't even produce a template (circle with 60 equal ticks on arc).

Comment: I'll suggest looking at `CirclePoints` and `GraphicsComplex` which lead to a very simple implementation to get the main shape.  It's a bit more work to get the labels if you want them.

Comment: I'll just [leave this here](https://imgur.com/rfHzteR). Here is the link to the code [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Mathematica/comments/422s6h/sir_kill_aka_a_visualization_of_a_nephroide/).

Comment: Related: [Plotting an epicycloid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32444/731). The cardioid is the special case of an epicycloid where the radius of both the circles is the same. Also related: [Animation with Cardano circles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112700/731). A Cardano circle is the corresponding special case of a hypocycloid where both the circles have the same radius.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using complex-number geometry and a sort of "converse" use of `GraphicsComplex` to [@Brett's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/177069/4999):

```
With[{n = 60, k = 2},
 With[{a = Exp[-2 Pi*I*Range[1., n]/n]},
  Graphics@GraphicsComplex[
    ReIm[I*Join[a, a^k]],
    {Circle[], Point@Range@n,
     RGBColor[0.94, 0.28, 0.68], 
     Line@Transpose@Partition[Range[2 n], n]}
    ]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I suggest the other two images in the OP have a different number of points than 60.  The Epicycloid of Cremona seems to have 150:

```
With[{n = 150, k = 4},
 With[{a = Exp[2 Pi*I*Range[1., n]/n]},
  Graphics@GraphicsComplex[
    ReIm[-Join[a, a^k]],
    {{Texture@ImageApply[0.7 # &, ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "BurlOak"}]], 
      Polygon[1.1 {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},
     Circle[],
     RGBColor[0.8562395526496464, 0.8409852478244543, 0.6735037273243409],
     Point@Range@n, Line@Transpose@Partition[Range[2 n], n]}
    ]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This approach uses twice the minimum memory needed, but the dependence on the multiplier `k` in the map $n \mapsto k\,n$ is reduced to the amazingly brief `a^k`. For instance, in `Manipulate`, this means the update from the kernel that is needed when `k` is changed can be isolated to updating the points of the `GraphicsComplex` (i.e., `ReIm[I*Join[a, a^k]]`):

```
SetSystemOptions["CheckMachineUnderflow" -> False]; (* For V11.3+ *)
Manipulate[
 With[{a = Exp[2 Pi*I*Range@n/n]},
  Graphics@GraphicsComplex[
    Dynamic@ReIm[I*Join[a, a^k]],
    {Thin, Circle[],
     Opacity[1/20 + 30/n], Line@Transpose@Partition[Range[2 n], n]}
    ]],
 {k, 2, 10, 1},
 {n, 60, 6000, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I turn off checking machine underflow, because [a change in V11.3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94996/machine-precision-near-zero-not-fulfilled) means a warning message is emitted that makes `Manipulate` red faced with anger.  This happens sometimes when the real or imaginary part (nearly) vanishes.  It doesn't even take very large or very small inputs for this to happen.  For example:

```
SetSystemOptions["CheckMachineUnderflow" -> True]; (* default setting *)
Exp[2 Pi*I/10.]^5
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Update: Labelling points*

Use [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html). Its syntax (specifically the `offset` parameter) does not play well with `GraphicsComplex`, and the easiest way to get the offsets is to recompute the real and imaginary parts of `a`:

```
With[{n = 60, k = 2},
 With[{a = Exp[-2 Pi*I*Range[1., n]/n]},
  Graphics@GraphicsComplex[
    ReIm[I*Join[a, a^k]],
    {Circle[], Point@Range@n, 
     MapThread[Text[#, #, #2] &, {Range@n, ReIm[-1.5 I*a]}],
     RGBColor[0.94, 0.28, 0.68], 
     Line@Transpose@Partition[Range[2 n], n]}
    ]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for another great answer. How can I actually `label` the points on the circle , like 1,2,3,...60 in the OP? I don't think `Tick` or `FrameTick` is the option.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have also just spotted the mistake in the picture too. `n` can not be 60 (mod 60). It must have been some larger values like you suggested!

Answer (score 17):

Using [`CirclePoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html), [`Mod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod.html), [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html)and [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html)

### More than enough lines

```
Multicolumn@With[
  {
   n = 500,
   m = 17
   },
  Table[
   Graphics[
    {Opacity[0.1],
     Through@{Point, Line}[
         Part[CirclePoints[n], Mod[{1, k } #, n] + 1]] & /@ Range[n]
     }
    ]
   , {k, 2, m}]
  ]
```

[image]

### Simpler

```
Multicolumn@With[
  {
   n = 100,
   m = 7
   },
  Table[
   Graphics[
    Through@{Point, Line}[
        Part[CirclePoints[n], Mod[{1, k } #, n] + 1]] & /@ Range[n]
    ]
   , {k, 2, m}]
  ]
```

[image]

### Original answer

Using [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html)

```
Module[
 {
  n = 161,
  coord, sequence, lines
  },
 coord = N@CirclePoints[n];
 sequence = 
  NestList[{Mod[#[[1]], n] + 1, Mod[#[[2]], n] + 2} &, {1, 1}, n - 2];
 lines = Map[Part[coord, #] &, sequence];
 Graphics[
  {
   Red,
   PointSize[Medium],
   Point[coord],
   Black, Opacity[0.2],
   Map[Line, lines, 1]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

For this I like to use `GraphicsComplex` to be able to think about the points using their index instead of dealing with the coordinates.

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[
    CirclePoints[{1, Pi/2 + 2 Pi/60}, 60], (* careful placement of points *)
    {
       {Circle[], Point[Range[60]]}, (* background elements *)
       {Red, Line[Table[{n, Mod[2 n, 60, 1]}, {n, 60}]]} (* main lines *)
    }
]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I may even add this to [How do I draw a pair of buttocks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66538/34893):

```
Graphics[Line /@ Table[{AngleVector[Pi n/60], AngleVector[Pi 3 n/60]}, {n, 0, 59}]]
```

[image]

Comment: To get the same figure as in the OP, change the number of points from `59` to `119`. The second figure is obtained by changing `3n` to `4n`, and changing the number of points to `239`. Etc.

Comment: This isn't quite the same graphic.

Comment: @BrettChampion This is half the Nephroid. As I mentioned in the comment above, to get the full figure one has to change `59` to `119`. To get the first image in the OP, one has to change `3n` to `2n`. Using other values such as `5n` or `7n`, one gets other similar figures.

Comment: AngleVector ? - Ah, new since 10.1 - Nice.

Answer (score 4):

I experimented with epicycloid envelopes a really long time ago; checking the file I got the basis of my code from shows that this was first done around version 4.

Since we are now in modern times, I have slightly modernized and compacted the code a bit, and then added it into a nice little `Manipulate[]` (which wasn't around during the time of version 4):

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{ColorData["Legacy", "Eggshell"], 
                     Table[Line[ReIm[Exp[I u {1, n + 1}]]],
                           {u, 0, 2 π Denominator[n], 2 π Denominator[n]/(m - 1)}]}, 
                    Background -> ColorData["Legacy", "VanDykeBrown"], 
                    Epilog -> {ColorData["Legacy", "Eggshell"], Circle[]}, 
                    PlotLabel -> Row[{"n = ", n}]],
           {{n, 1}, 1/12, 6, 1/12}, {{m, 61, "# of lines"}, 11, 501}]
```

[image: epicycloid Manipulate]

Another striking example:

[image: epicycloid again]

Answer (score 0):

```
Manipulate[
 With[{f = ReIm[-I (-1.)^(2/n #)] &}, 
  Graphics[{Circle[], 
    Table[{Circle[#, .015], Text[Style[If[Mod[i, 10] == 0, i, ""], 14], 1.1 #]} & @ f@i, 
      {i, 0, n - 1}], Magenta, Arrow@Table[f@{i, k i}, {i, x - 1}]}]],
 {n, 60, 200, 10}, {x, 1, n, 1}, {k, 2, 9, 1}]
```

[image]

The following picture generated with Mathematica and POV-Ray

[image]