# Direction of text when labelling graphs

Tags: graphics, labeling, text

On a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/177065/how-to-visualize-the-cremona-method-for-cardioid-generation) to this, I am now experimenting the labelling with the circle points,

```
With[{n = 150, k = 2}, 
With[{a = Exp[-2 Pi*I*Range[1., n]/n]}, 
    Graphics@GraphicsComplex[
        ReIm[I*Join[a, a^k]], {
            Circle[], 
            {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@Range@n}, 
            MapThread[
                Text[#, #, #2] &,
                {5 Range@30, ReIm[-1.5 I*a[[5 Range@30]]]}
            ]
        }
    ]
]]
```

Since it's difficult to label all numbers, I am only labelling every 5 points.

[image]

But, I am wondering, is it possible to efficiently change the direction of the texts, so that I `CAN` then label all points, like this

[image]

Or label the numbers by veritcally stacking the digits like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way: Use the third and fourth  arguments of `Text` to control the alignment and direction:

```
With[{n = 150, k = 2}, 
 With[{a = Exp[-2 Pi*I*Range[1., n]/n]}, 
      Graphics@GraphicsComplex[
            ReIm[I*Join[a, a^k]], {
                 Circle[], 
                 {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@Range@n}, 
                 MapThread[Text[#, #2, {-1, 0}, #2] &,
                      {RotateRight[5 Range@30, 75], 
                       ReIm[-1.05 I a[[5 Range@30]]]}
                  ]
             }
        ]
  ]]
```

[image]

To change the direction of text, use `Text[#, #2, {1,0}, -#2] &` as the first argument of `MapThread`:

[image]

To get more readable labels, use `Text[ #, #2, {d =If[#<=75, -1,1],0}, -d #2] &`:

[image]

Use `Text[Row[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ IntegerDigits[#], " "], #2, {1,0}, -#2] &` to get something similar to your third picture:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use

```
MapThread[Inset[Text@#, #2, Right, Automatic, -#2] &, 
 {RotateRight[5 Range@30, 75], ReIm[-1.05 I a[[5 Range@30]]]}]
```

and

```
MapThread[Inset[Text@#, #2, Left, Automatic, #2] &, 
 {RotateRight[5 Range@30, 75], ReIm[-1.05 I a[[5 Range@30]]]}]
```

to get similar pictures to the the first two pictures above.

Comment: I might also have some font size problems to adjust as I can't exactly reproduce using the same code ... but that's very helpful and enough for me to tweak around!