# How can I plot a Farey diagram?

Tags: plotting, graphics, number-theory

How can I plot the following diagram for a Farey series?

[image]

Comment: From the beautiful book A. Hatcher Topology of numbers

Comment: Could you perhaps expand a bit on how the curves are calculated etc?

Comment: http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNch1.pdf

Comment: Technically this is not a Farey series/sequence $F_n$ of order $n$, which is defined to be all fractions (sometimes restricted to the interval between 0 and 1) with denominator at most $n$.  For example 3/8 is present but not 1/8.  It's a recursive mediant subdivision.  It's related in that in any three successive terms of a Farey sequence, the middle one is the mediant of the other two.

Comment: If it wasn't for the very good answers you got, I would have voted to close this question as it gives no details, no definitions no code and shows no personal effort. Please, next time try asking [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Comment: rhermans have reason. The question comes trying to construct the true diagram for the farey sequence since I got these points no symmetrically distributed around the circle  Show[Graphics[{Gray, Circle[]}], {Map[
   Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[{ReIm[Exp[Pi/2 I #]]}]}] &,
    FareySequence[7]]}, PlotRange -> All]

Answer (score 15):

The curvilinear triangles which are characteristic for this type of plot are called hypocycloid curves. We can use the parametric equations on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid) to plot these, like so:

```
x[a_, b_, t_] := (b - a) Cos[t] + a Cos[(b - a)/a t]
y[a_, b_, t_] := (b - a) Sin[t] - a Sin[(b - a)/a t]
hypocycloid[n_] := ParametricPlot[
  {x[1/n, 1, t], y[1/n, 1, t]},
  {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002], Black}
  ]

Show[
 Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]],
 hypocycloid[2],
 hypocycloid[4],
 hypocycloid[8],
 hypocycloid[16],
 hypocycloid[32],
 hypocycloid[64],
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've previously written about an application of hypocycloids [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112772/731), and I showed how to visualize epicycloids [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32456/731).

How to generate the labels is described [here](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNch1.pdf) (also linked to by moo in a comment). I will simply provide the code.

```
mediant[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}] := {a + c, b + d}
recursive[v1_, v2_, depth_] := If[
  depth > 2,
  mediant[v1, v2], {
   recursive[v1, mediant[v1, v2], depth + 1],
   mediant[v1, v2],
   recursive[mediant[v1, v2], v2, depth + 1]
   }]

computeLabels[v1_, v2_] := Module[{numbers},
  numbers = 
   Cases[recursive[v1, v2, 0], {_Integer, _Integer}, Infinity];
  StringTemplate["``/``"] @@@ numbers
  ]
computeLabelsNegative[v1_, v2_] := Module[{numbers},
  numbers = 
   Cases[recursive[v1, v2, 0], {_Integer, _Integer}, Infinity];
  StringTemplate["-`2`/`1`"] @@@ numbers
  ]

labels = Reverse@Join[
    {"1/0"},
    computeLabels[{1, 0}, {1, 1}],
    {"1/1"},
    computeLabels[{1, 1}, {0, 1}],
    {"0/1"},
    computeLabelsNegative[{1, 0}, {1, 1}],
    {"-1,1"},
    computeLabelsNegative[{1, 1}, {0, 1}]
    ];

coords = CirclePoints[{1.1, 186 Degree}, 64];

Show[
 Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]],
 hypocycloid[2],
 hypocycloid[4],
 hypocycloid[8],
 hypocycloid[16],
 hypocycloid[32],
 hypocycloid[64],
 Graphics@MapThread[Text, {labels, coords}],
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

Using Graph with a bit of coding:

```
addPoint[{p : h_[a_,b_], q : h_[c_,d_]}, i_] :=
    With[{np = h[a + c, b + d]}, Sow[{p \[UndirectedEdge] np, np \[UndirectedEdge] q}]; Sow[{i, i}, "Depth"]; {p, np, q}]

addPoint[{p : h_[a_,b_], q : h_[-1][c_,d_]}, i_] :=
    With[{np = h[-1][a + c, b + d]}, Sow[{p \[UndirectedEdge] np, np \[UndirectedEdge] q}]; Sow[{i, i}, "Depth"]; {p, np, q}]

addPoint[{p : h_[-1][a_,b_], q : h_[c_,d_]}, i_] :=
    With[{np = h[-1][a + c, b + d]}, Sow[{p \[UndirectedEdge] np, np \[UndirectedEdge] q}]; Sow[{i, i}, "Depth"]; {p, np, q}]

addPoint[{p : h_[-1][a_,b_], q : h_[-1][c_,d_]}, i_] :=
    With[{np = h[-1][a + c, b + d]}, Sow[{p \[UndirectedEdge] np, np \[UndirectedEdge] q}]; Sow[{i, i}, "Depth"]; {p, np, q}]

fLabel[fr_, angle_] := 
    With[{tangle=ArcTan@@angle}, Placed[fLabel[fr], AngleVector[{1/2, 1/2}, {.7, #}] & /@{tangle, tangle+Pi}]]

fLabel[h_[a_, b_]] := ToString[a] ~~ "/" ~~ ToString[b]
fLabel[h_[-1][a_, b_]] := "-" ~~ ToString[a] ~~ "/" ~~ ToString[b]

FareyDiagram[n_Integer, d_Integer: 1, opts___?OptionQ] :=
    Block[{fr, top, bottom, stedges, toppart, bottompart, vert, edges, coords, labels, labpos, cfunc, i, edgestyle, dstyle, nopts},
        cfunc = ColorFunction /. Flatten[{opts}] /. ColorFunction -> Automatic;
        nopts = FilterRules[Flatten[{opts}], Options[Graph]];
        top = {fr[0,1], fr[1,1], fr[1,0]};
        bottom = {fr[1,0], fr[-1][1,1], fr[0,1]};
        stedges = UndirectedEdge@@@Join[Partition[top, 2, 1], Partition[bottom, 2, 1], {{fr[0, 1],fr[1, 0]}}];
        i = 0;toppart = Reap[Nest[(i++; Split[Flatten[addPoint[#, i] & /@ Partition[#, 2, 1],1]][[All,1]])&, top, n]];
        i = 0;bottompart = Reap[Nest[(i++; Split[Flatten[addPoint[#, i] & /@ Partition[#,2,1],1]][[All,1]])&,bottom, n]];
        vert = Join[toppart[[1]], bottompart[[1,  2;;-2]]];
        edges = Flatten[{stedges, toppart[[2, 1]], bottompart[[2, 1]]}];
        coords = CirclePoints[{1,0},Length[vert]];
        labpos = Range[1, Length[vert], 2 ^ (d - 1)];
        labels = Thread[vert[[labpos]]->fLabel@@@Transpose[{vert,coords}][[labpos]]];
        edgestyle = Black;
        dstyle = Black;
        If[cfunc =!= Automatic,
            edgestyle = Flatten[{Table[0, Length[stedges]], toppart[[2, 2]], bottompart[[2, 2]]}];
            edgestyle = edgestyle / Max[edgestyle];
            edgestyle = Thread[edges -> Flatten[cfunc[1 - #] & /@ edgestyle]];
            dstyle = cfunc[1]
         ];
        Graph[vert, edges, nopts, VertexCoordinates->CirclePoints[{1,0},Length[vert]], VertexLabels->labels, 
           EdgeShapeFunction->(BSplineCurve[{#1[[1]],{0,0},#1[[2]]}, SplineWeights->{2,EuclideanDistance@@#,2}]&), 
           PerformanceGoal->"Speed", Epilog->{dstyle, Circle[]}, VertexShapeFunction -> "Point", EdgeStyle -> edgestyle, VertexStyle -> dstyle]
    ]
```

Example:

```
FareyDiagram[4]
```

[image]

```
FareyDiagram[6, 4, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Darker[Red]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I looked up the [Farey sequence on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence), out of curiosity, because I had not heard of it before. The Farey sequence of order $n$ is "the sequence of completely reduced fractions between 0 and 1 which, when in lowest terms, have denominators less than or equal to $n$, arranged in order of increasing size".

On that basis, you can generate the sequence as follows, for instance:

```
ClearAll[farey]
farey[n_Integer] := (Divide @@@ Subsets[Range[n], {2}]) ~ Join ~ {0, 1} //DeleteDuplicates //Sort
```

So for instance:

```
farey[5]
```

> {0, 1/5, 1/4, 1/3, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 1}

I am not sure how these sequences are connected with the figure you showed though.

Comment: Thanks to C.E.,  it is a concrete answer

Comment: Built in too: [FareySequence](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FareySequence.html)

Comment: @KennyColnago Oh man! How did I miss that?! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

While reading an excellent [post on chord diagrams](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1744863), I realized that this type of figure is a Poincaré hyperbolic disk. The lines are Poincaré arcs. There is MathWorld article with code [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoincareHyperbolicDisk.html).

So, copying the definitions of `PoincareArc` and `PoincareDisk` from MathWorld, we can draw the figure like this:

```
PoincareArc[l0_List] := 
 Module[{l = Sort[l0], dt, t, t1, t2, r, R, c},
  dt = Abs[l[[1]] - l[[2]]];
  t = Plus @@ l/2;
  If[
   dt == Pi,
   Line[{
     {Cos[l[[1]]], Sin[l[[1]]]},
     {Cos[l[[2]]], Sin[l[[2]]]}
     }], c = {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
   r = Tan[dt/2];
   R = Sec[dt/2];
   t1 = ArcTan @@ ({Cos[l[[2]]], Sin[l[[2]]]} - R c);
   t2 = ArcTan @@ ({Cos[l[[1]]], Sin[l[[1]]]} - R c);
   If[t2 < t1, t2 += 2 Pi];
   Circle[R c, r, {t1, t2}]]]

PoincareDisk[l_List] := 
 Module[{i}, {{Thickness[.001], Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}, 
   Table[PoincareArc[l[[i]]], {i, Length[l]}]}]

angles[n_] := Partition[Table[th, {th, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n}], 2, 1]

Graphics[{
  PoincareDisk@angles[2],
  PoincareDisk@angles[4],
  PoincareDisk@angles[8],
  PoincareDisk@angles[16],
  PoincareDisk@angles[32],
  PoincareDisk@angles[64]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to use `Graph`: Using `CycleGraph`s with `2^k` vertices and the internal edge shape function `` GraphComputation`GraphChartDump`pEdge ``:

```
Quiet[GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[]];
eSF = GraphComputation`GraphChartDump`pEdge[#2[[1]], blah, blah, ##] &;

Show[CycleGraph[2^#, VertexSize -> 0, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, 
   EdgeStyle -> Black] & /@ Range[5], Epilog -> Circle[]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use a function to define the edge list to be used in a single `Graph`:

```
ClearAll[vPairs]
vPairs[k_Integer] := DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ 
  (Partition[Append[#, 1], 2, 1] & /@ Range[1, 2^k, 2^Range[0, k-1]])]

Graph[Range[2^k], vPairs[k], 
  EdgeStyle->Black,
  VertexShape -> Graphics[{}], 
  Epilog -> Circle[],
  EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF,
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding",
  ImageSize -> 300]
```

> same picture

With colored edges:

```
Row[(colors = RotateRight @ ColorData[97, "ColorList"];
  Show[CycleGraph[2^#, VertexSize -> 0, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, 
         EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, First[colors = RotateLeft[colors]]]] & /@ Range[#], 
    Epilog -> Circle[], ImageSize -> 300]) & /@ Range[2, 5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
grupo[n_] := Show[{Graphics[{Thin, Red, 
Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi/2}]}]}, {Graphics[{Thin, 
Map[{BSplineCurve[{#1[[1]], {0, 0}, #1[[2]]}, 
SplineWeights -> {2, EuclideanDistance @@ 
#,2}]}&, 
Partition[ReIm[Exp[Pi/2 I #]] & /@
FareySequence[n], 2, 1]]}]}, {Map[Graphics[{Blue, 
Point[{ReIm[Exp[Pi/2 I #]]}]}] &, 
FareySequence[n]]}, PlotRange -> All]

Show[Table[grupo[n], {n, 2, 7}]]
```

[image]

Comment: the true farey diagram based on the answers given above