# Map a function with multiple parameters to a list of lists (use of slot)

Tags: list-manipulation, parametric-functions, map

I want to learn how to apply core functions with multiple parameters with no need to name new functions taking multiple variables.

I looked at [Mapping multiple parameters of a function to specific values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/mapping-multiple-parameters-of-a-function-to-specific-values) , [How to Map a subset of list elements to a function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4061/44334) and would like to iterate to a list of lists.

This is my example.

I have a list of lists:

```
{{"Absolute risk reduction", "Medicine"}, {"Absorption cross section","Medicine"}, {"Abutment", "Dentistry", "Medicine"}}
```

I want to use `Riffle[a, b]` and apply

```
Riffle[{"Abutment", "Dentistry", "Medicine"}, "."]
```

for each of them, here `b = "."`

**I can map a function with one parameter, but how to with multiple ones in one line?**

Desired output:

```
{{"Abutment", ".", "Dentistry", ".", "Medicine"} .. }
```

I tried:

```
(* Map[Reverse, %180] is the lists of list evaluation *)

Riffle[{"."}, #] & /@ Map[Reverse, %180]
(* {{"."}, {"."}, {"."}}*)

Map[Riffle[{"."}, #] &, Map[Reverse, %180]]
(* {{"."}, {"."}, {"."}}*)

Riffle @@ {Map[Reverse, %180][[#]], {"."}} &
(* Riffle @@ {(Reverse /@ %180)[[#1]], {"."}} & *)
```

**Why the first two returns a list of lists of dots and not the desired output?**

Can you explain what is doing the third syntax?

Comment: Did you want `Riffle[#, "."] & /@ list` ?

Comment: Yes... Could you explain the difference in using `Riffle[#, "."] & /@ list` then `Riffle[".", #] & /@ list` ? And why `Riffle[{"."}, #] & /@ list` replaces with dots instead of "riffling"?

Comment: `Riffle[list, item]` returns `list` with `item` inserted into the "gaps" between elements. If `list` is only one element long, there are no gaps, so `list` is returned unchanged. This is noted in the documentation for [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html): *Riffle[{e}, x] gives {e}*

Answer (score 3):

As already commented by [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130733/map-a-function-with-multiple-parameters-to-a-list-of-lists-use-of-slot#comment352907_130733).

Here is the result using the examples given:

```
words = {{"Absolute risk reduction", 
   "Medicine"}, {"Absorption cross section", "Medicine"}, {"Abutment",
    "Dentistry", "Medicine"}}
```

> {{"Absolute risk reduction", "Medicine"}, {"Absorption cross section",
>      "Medicine"}, {"Abutment", "Dentistry", "Medicine"}}

```
Riffle[#, "."] & /@ words
```

> {{"Absolute risk reduction", ".", 
>     "Medicine"}, {"Absorption cross section", ".", 
>     "Medicine"}, {"Abutment", ".", "Dentistry", ".", "Medicine"}}